# Running a bash command with a boolean check in Vim

Tags: bash, vim, ctags

In Vim, every time I write to a file, I want the ctags for my project to be regenerated, but only if a `.ctags` config file exists in the root directory of the project. To achieve this, I am trying to add the following to my `~/.vimrc`

```
map <Leader>w :w | !test -f .ctags && ctags --options=.ctags .<CR>
```

However, when I try to run it, I get dropped back into bash with the following output:

```
$ vim . 
shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I suspect this is being caused by the `&&` not being parsed correctly in the `~/.vimrc`, however after messing with the syntax for a fair number of minutes, I'm stumped. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is seeing a map definition (`map <Leader>w :w`) and a separate shell invocation (`!test -f .ctags && ctags --options=.ctags .<CR>`); the `|` separator has to be escaped inside a mapping; cp. [`:help map-bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-bar)

```
map <Leader>w :w<Bar>!test -f .ctags && ctags --options=.ctags .<CR>
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion, and probably limit the mapping to *normal mode*:

```
nnoremap <Leader>w :w<Bar>!test -f .ctags && ctags --options=.ctags .<CR>
```

To avoid the `shell returned 1` when the tags database doesn't exist, actually, to skip the whole shell invocation in that case, better do the file existence check in Vimscript:

```
nnoremap <Leader>w :w<Bar>if filereadable('.ctags')<Bar>execute '!ctags --options=.ctags .'<Bar>endif<CR>
```

We have to wrap the `:!` command in execute so it doesn't swallow the `:endif`; cp. [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar).

As a final tweak, I would replace `:write` with `:update`, which does not re-write the buffer contents if it's already been persisted:

```
nnoremap <Leader>w :update<Bar>if filereadable('.ctags')<Bar>execute '!ctags --options=.ctags .'<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Comment: The last one you provided is very close to what I settled on. The only problem with it is it still drops me into the terminal with the ```Press ENTER or type command to continue``` message. I got around it by adding an extra <CR> at the end of the command, however my screen flashes everytime I use the command, which is a minor annoyance.

Comment: Also thanks for your thorough answer, complete with references to the manual!

Comment: Try using `silent! execute`; that should get rid of the output and the Hit - enter.

Comment: Yeah, that just causes the terminal to blackout. Once you send a few commands to vim though, everything except the contents of the currently open buffers re-renders.